# Decoding Json string in PHP

Tags: php, json

My Json encoded output is like the below one

```
    {
    "msg_id":"14789",
    "message":"dummy+message",
    "msgType":"TEXT",
    "sendondate":"2013-12-26 13:19:49",
    "seq_id":{
        "1":{
            "valid":"true",
            "credit":"1.00",
            "linecount":1,
            "billcredit":1,
            "id_provider":"18",
            "providerkey":"TI",
            "regionKey":"CH",
            "originalnumber":"11",
            "validnumber":"+11",
            "countryprefix":"11",
            "ONLYNUMBER":"11",
            "NUMBERWITHZERO":"11",
            "INTERNATIONALONLY":"11",
            "INTERNATIONALWITHPLUS":"+11",
            "mnpID":"905",
            "dlr_seq":1,
            "textMessage":"dummy+message",
            "status":"",
            "remarks":""
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print the value for billcredit as output. How can I decode this in php?

Comment: use `json_decode` function.

Comment: Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode): https://eval.in/83113

Comment: Thanks Amal Murali :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you want to get with [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$string = '{"msg_id":"14789","message":"dummy+message","msgType":"TEXT","sendondate":"2013-12-26 13:19:49","seq_id":{"1":{"valid":"true","credit":"1.00","linecount":1,"billcredit":1,"id_provider":"18","providerkey":"TI","regionKey":"CH","originalnumber":"11","validnumber":"+11","countryprefix":"11","ONLYNUMBER":"11","NUMBERWITHZERO":"11","INTERNATIONALONLY":"11","INTERNATIONALWITHPLUS":"+11","mnpID":"905","dlr_seq":1,"textMessage":"dummy+message","status":"","remarks":""}}}';

// Return Object Data
print_r( json_decode($string) );
// Return Array Data
print_r( json_decode($string, true) );

$decoded_data = json_decode($string, true);
// Bill Credit Value
echo "billcredit: " . $decoded_data['seq_id'][1]['billcredit'];
```

http://codepad.org/BJ5KbHVq

Comment: i just want to print value of billcredit. How can I specifically mention it?

Comment: @Alien2828 check the updated codes.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

```
$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'};
```

For more about json in php visit the [link](http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: or `$asAssocArray = json_decode($json, true); echo $asAssocArray['foo-bar'];` link to docs, might complete your answer

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$your_data_in_array_comes_here = json_decode("Your Output String");

With above array you can generate html as your wish.
```